# _taccess() function used for DVD-ROM in WinXP and Win7

Tags: windows, winapi, dvd

I've got a problem when using _taccess() function:

```
int nAccess = _taccess("x:", 06);
```

`x` is my DVD-ROM. This function returns different result in WinXP and Win7:
in WinXP, the function returns -1, which indicates it is NOT writable.
But in Win7, the function returns 0, which indicates it is writable.

How does it happen? 
So what can I do if I want to check DVD-ROM (such as "x:") writable?

Comment: Just to be clear, is the disc in the drive writable (burnable)?

Comment: A DVD-ROM is never writeable. Why would you need to check that? Are you talking about a *drive* or a *disc*?

Comment: Sorry, my description is not clear. I want to check the writability of a disc, such as DVD-R or DVD-RAM disc.